# how to init Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore

Tags: amazon-s3

i need to check if a bucket exist on S3, and have following code:

```
public static final String S3_URI = "s3n://accessKey:secretKey";

FileSystem fs = new NativeS3FileSystem(new Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore(S3_URI, null));
if (!fs.exists(bucket)) {
     getLogger().error("The input directory '{}' does not exists.", bucket);
     return false;
}
```

but eclipse complained cannot resolve Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore to a type, and the imports statements complained org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore is not visible. checked the source code for Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore, it's

```
class Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore implements NativeFileSystemStore {

  private S3Service s3Service;
  private S3Bucket bucket;
  ...
```

does that mean it's a private class? what's the right way to check if bucket exist on S3?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is package-private.  You can only access it from the same java package.  Although nothing prevents you from declaring things in that package, it is an ugly hack.  Isn't there a static method on `FileSystem` that can serve up the appropriate file system for any URL, including s3n://?

Comment: yes, use NativeS3FileSystem instead and call the exists() directly, it works. thanks